# Swift - Weird output in label field

Tags: ios, swift

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("file", ofType: "log")
var text = String(contentsOfFile: path!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)!

var textArr = text.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
            var rad: String = textArr[n]
....

println(rad)
label.text = "\(label.text) \(rad)"
```

In Xcode Output window I get this:

```
CORRECT LINE 
NEXT LINE
```

In label field in Simulator I get this:

```
Optional("Optional("Optional(\\\"\\\")
CORRECT LINE\\r\") NEXT LINE \r")
```

I would like the label field to look like the output in Xcode, where do all this Optional\\"r -stuff come from?

Comment: The `\r` are newline characters coming from the logfile you read in.

Comment: That's because your variables are optional, you can use ! at the end of the variables to make them non-nullable (if they are indeed not null).
Though here you just want to concatenate two strings, use instead ```label.text = label.text ?? "" + rad```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Where do you mean the "!" should be placed? New to swift. 
Unfortunately "label.text = label.text ?? "" + rad" didn't quite work for me, the label-field turns out all blank?

Comment: It seems to be working now. So for update if anyone else get the same problem.
This solved it, as christen said: label.text = "\(label.text!)\(rad)"